# wrap c++ method with a c method

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I have a class:

```
class C {
public:
   int func1 (int arg1, int arg2) { return 1; }
   float func2 (float arg1, float arg2) { return 2; }
} ;
```

I would like to create a C wrapper function for the methods func1 and func2 and then cast it to a void function pointer.

```
typedef void (*Function)(void);
typedef Function *FunctionPtr;

FunctionPtr functions[] = {
  (FunctionPtr)&Wrap<&C::func1>::f,
  (FunctionPtr)&Wrap<&C::func2>::f
};
```

After which I could cast them back to C function pointers and use them:

```
Class C c;

typedef int (*MyIntFunction)(C *c, int arg1, int arg2);
MyIntFunction *mif = (MyIntFunction *)functions[0];
int ri = (*mif)(&c, 1, 2);

typedef float (*MyFloatFunction)(C *c, float arg1, float arg2);
MyFloatFunction *mff = (MyFloatFunction *)functions[1];
float rf = (*mff)(&c, 1, 2);
```

I have been experimenting with various templating magics, but have not found the right way so far of doing this.

Comment: How do you expect to declare a class in C?

Comment: Casting function pointers to data pointers (`void*`) is undefined behavior.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Are you cresting a shared library and want a `C` interface to the underlying `C++` implementation?

Comment: 1. I am not declaring a class in C
2. casting to a void function pointer is fine too
3. in a nutshell yes, but with a specific need in mind

Comment: edited to reflect StoryTeller's comment

Comment: @StoryTeller: I think the word you're looking for is _conditionally supported_. It used to be UB back in C++98.

Comment: @MSalters I wasn't looking, but thanks for pointing it out. Haven't visited that part of the standard in a while. I still think it's better avoided for the sake of portability.

Answer (score 4):

You can *not* use either classes or templates in C code. To wrap a C++ function, you have to create a C wrapper for every C++ function. In a header:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int C_func1( void *obj, int arg1, int arg2 );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

In a `.cpp`:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

int C_func1( void *obj, int arg1, int arg2 ) {
    C *const that = static_cast<C*>(obj);
    return that->func1( arg1, arg2 );
}

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Repeat for `C::func2`, and so on.

Comment: Also you might want to use a macro with variadic argument list to simplify creation of these wrapper functions.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen You'd need 4 versions of the macro: (1) no-return with no-args (2) return with no-args (3) no-return with args (4) return with args.

Comment: While this is a solution to "creating a wrapper for a c++ function with a  c function," it does not "automate it" using the magic of templates in anyway.  I am looking for a solution where I can say: "(FunctionPtr)&Wrap<&C::func1>::f" or something similar.  (As I stated in the second sentence of the question).  I build a function table in the C++ code, and then use this function table in C code.   --I will not mark this as a correct answer.

Comment: @iamacomputer You can _not_ convert a pointer-to-member-function to an ordinary pointer-to-function. You also can not mix pointers to functions of various types because the signatures differ. There is no way to do what you're asking.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas There is a way.  I'm not trying to convert a member function pointer to an ordinary pointer-to-function..  I'm trying to specialize a templated class, with has a static function, which calls the member function of the provided class instance.

Comment: @iamacomputer I re-read your original post and that's exactly what you say you want to do. Your example shows non-static member functions.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm going to post my answer of my "not-so-great-solution."  I'm really hoping for something better than mine.

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
struct MemberFunctionPointer
{
    typedef R Return;
    typedef C Class;
};

template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
constexpr auto inferMemberFunctionPointer(R (C::*method)(A...))
{
    return MemberFunctionPointer<R,C,A...>{};
}

template<typename M, M m, typename... A>
class WrapMemberFunction
{
    typedef typename decltype(inferMemberFunctionPointer(m))::Class T;
    typedef typename decltype(inferMemberFunctionPointer(m))::Return R;
public:
    static R f (T *t, A... args) {
        return (t->*m)(args...);
    }

} ;

#define WrapMember(TM) (FunctionPtr)&WrapMemberFunction<decltype(&TM), &TM>::f
#define WrapMemberA(TM, args...) (FunctionPtr)&WrapMemberFunction<decltype(&TM), &TM, args>::f
```

I believe this causes the compiler to:

1. infer the return and class (obviously)
2. create a specialized template class which has a static function which calls the specified member function
3. allow this specialized template class static function to be referenced as an exportable C function.

And you can write things like:

```
FunctionPtr f = WrapMember(MyClass::MyFunction);
```

Unfortunately in my approach, the macro is necessary, which I don't like.

I've tried many things to get rid of this macro..  To no avail, such as this:

```
template<typename R, typename C, typename... A>
constexpr auto binderX(R (C::*m)(A...))
{
    typedef decltype(m) M;
    return &WrapMemberFunction<M, m, A...>::f;
}

FunctionPtr _x = binderX(&SimpleVector::printOther);
```

Comment: Have you actually tried calling one of these wrapped functional? Does it actually work?

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I've finally come to, I think, the simplest manner of accomplishing what I want:

```
template<typename M, M m, typename T, typename... A>
class WrapMemberFunctionV
{
public:
    static void f (T *t, A... args) {
        (t->*m)(args...);
    }
} ;

template<typename M, M m, typename R, typename T, typename... A>
class WrapMemberFunction
{
public:
    static R f (T *t, A... args) {
        return (t->*m)(args...);
    }
} ;

template<typename M, M m, typename R, typename C, typename... A>
constexpr auto generateCompileTimeWrapper(R (C::*method)(A...))
{
    return &WrapMemberFunction<M, m, R, C, A...>::f;
}

template<typename M, M m, typename C, typename... A>
constexpr auto generateCompileTimeWrapper(void (C::*method)(A...))
{
    return &WrapMemberFunctionV<M, m, C, A...>::f;
}

#define WrapMethod(TM) generateCompileTimeWrapper<decltype(&TM), &TM>(&TM)
```

use like so:

```
auto m = WrapMethod(MyClass::myMethod);
```

for my purposes, I need to detect whether there is a return value.  (instead of void).  If you do not need special code for this, you can remove WrapMemberFunctionV and just use the other.  for both no return (void) and value return.